# Reading file After a special character delimiter in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file in which sentences ends like ./.
I want to read the file in a cell array, one cell for every line. Could you please tell me how to do that using textscan.
Basically I want to know how to put the delimiter ./.

Answer (score 1):

well i am not sure if this is helpful or not

in the normal case of a new line for each sentence you could use

```
  tline = fgetl(fileID);
  D=textscan(tline,'%s','delimiter','./.');
```

but if your file doesn't have new lines for each sentence just ./. as a separator there are two cases  that the sentences don't contain any characters used as a delimiter i.e  . or /
in that case you can try something like

```
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %*1s','delimiter','/','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

the other case if your sentences did contain these characters then i think you can't use them as a delimiters  but i might be wrong